# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit only shows 4GB RAM out of 8GB recognized

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, ram

I have two memory cards of 4GB = 8GB RAM installed and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit only shows 4GB RAM. How can I make it show the whole 8GB?

You can see the details below, I have also included some graphics (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650) info just in case it was eating the RAM memory.

It's a HP Pavilion dv7-4012eg with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz btw.

```
jessy@linx:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3887       1850       2036          3        285        745
-/+ buffers/cache:        819       3067
Swap:         8192          0       8192

jessy@linx:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 17
[sudo] password for jessy: 
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: 0x0019
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - Slot 1
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 977A35A0
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: M471B5173BH0-CK0  
    Rank: 1

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: 0x001C
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - Slot 2
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Nanya
    Serial Number: 0676036D
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: M2S4G64CB8HG5N-DI 
    Rank: 2


jessy@linx:~$ sudo lshw -c memory
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: F.29
       date: 11/07/2011
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1472KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification
  *-cache:0
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 15
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-through unified
  *-cache:2
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 16
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-through instruction
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 14
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-through data
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 17
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: M471B5173BH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 977A35A0
          slot: Bottom - Slot 1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: M2S4G64CB8HG5N-DI
          vendor: Nanya
          physical id: 1
          serial: 0676036D
          slot: Bottom - Slot 2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)

jessy@linx:~$ dmesg | grep e820
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bbe3efff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bbe3f000-0x00000000bbebefff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bbebf000-0x00000000bbfbefff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bbfbf000-0x00000000bbffefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bbfff000-0x00000000bbffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bc000000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb00000-0x00000000feb03fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed10000-0x00000000fed13fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed18000-0x00000000fed19fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1b000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffe80000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000013fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x140000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0xbc000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0xc0000000-0xefffffff] available for PCI devices
[    1.215263] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009d000-0x0009ffff]
[    1.215265] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xbbe3f000-0xbbffffff]

jessy@linx:~$ sudo dmesg | grep drm
[sudo] password for jessy: 
[   19.533784] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   19.595888] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   19.596328] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (REDWOOD 0x1002:0x68C1 0x103C:0x1449).
[   19.596370] [drm] register mmio base: 0xD4000000
[   19.596373] [drm] register mmio size: 131072
[   19.596610] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=256M
[   19.596613] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[   19.598366] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[   19.598369] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   19.598443] [drm] Loading REDWOOD Microcode
[   20.529509] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[   20.531705] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 2 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[   20.551741] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025D000).
[   20.553301] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   20.553302] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   20.553386] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   20.570449] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   20.570464] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 6 usecs
[   20.756575] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 2 usecs
[   20.756588] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   20.756969] [drm] Enabling audio 0 support
[   20.757033] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   20.757091] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   20.908562] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[   20.965712] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[   20.965717] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   20.965720] [drm] Connector 0:
[   20.965722] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   20.965725] [drm]   DDC: 0x6560 0x6560 0x6564 0x6564 0x6568 0x6568 0x656c 0x656c
[   20.965726] [drm]   Encoders:
[   20.965728] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   20.965730] [drm] Connector 1:
[   20.965731] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[   20.965733] [drm]   HPD1
[   20.965735] [drm]   DDC: 0x6430 0x6430 0x6434 0x6434 0x6438 0x6438 0x643c 0x643c
[   20.965737] [drm]   Encoders:
[   20.965738] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY1
[   20.965740] [drm] Connector 2:
[   20.965741] [drm]   VGA-1
[   20.965744] [drm]   DDC: 0x64d8 0x64d8 0x64dc 0x64dc 0x64e0 0x64e0 0x64e4 0x64e4
[   20.965745] [drm]   Encoders:
[   20.965747] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   20.965825] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[   21.029449] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   21.889804] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC045E000
[   21.889808] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[   21.889810] [drm] size 5787648
[   21.889812] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   21.889814] [drm]    pitch is 6400
[   21.890122] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   23.808455] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   23.808578] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.36.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   61.998447] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep bluetooth nls_utf8 cifs fscache snd_hda_codec_hdmi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev hp_wmi sparse_keymap arc4 snd_hda_codec_idt coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep ath9k kvm snd_pcm ath9k_common ath9k_hw snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi ath snd_seq_midi_event radeon snd_rawmidi mac80211 joydev serio_raw i7core_edac edac_core cfg80211 snd_seq ttm snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper snd_timer lpc_ich mei_me drm mei snd soundcore i2c_algo_bit wmi hp_accel lis3lv02d video input_polldev mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ahci psmouse r8169 libahci mii

jessy@linx:~$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7a4c688d009fc1f06ffc692f5f42ab09e68582b2, stripped

jessy@linx:~$ uname -a
Linux linx 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

jessy@linx:~$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3980292 kB
MemFree:          215584 kB
Buffers:          266516 kB
Cached:           962476 kB
SwapCached:           12 kB
Active:          2545688 kB
Inactive:         879940 kB
Active(anon):    1943544 kB
Inactive(anon):   278912 kB
Active(file):     602144 kB
Inactive(file):   601028 kB
Unevictable:         724 kB
Mlocked:             724 kB
SwapTotal:       8389596 kB
SwapFree:        8388180 kB
Dirty:               152 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2197400 kB
Mapped:           294696 kB
Shmem:             25820 kB
Slab:             205660 kB
SReclaimable:      88652 kB
SUnreclaim:       117008 kB
KernelStack:        6208 kB
PageTables:        52164 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10379740 kB
Committed_AS:    7787880 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      161204 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359566624 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    407552 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       84224 kB
DirectMap2M:     4042752 kB

jessy@linx:~$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
[sudo] password for jessy: 
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: 0x0019
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - Slot 1
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 977A35A0
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: M471B5173BH0-CK0  
    Rank: 1

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: 0x001C
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - Slot 2
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Nanya
    Serial Number: 0676036D
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: M2S4G64CB8HG5N-DI 
    Rank: 2

jessy@linx:~$ sudo dmesg | grep "Memory"
[    0.000000] Memory: 3958676K/4126576K available (7383K kernel code, 1144K rwdata, 3408K rodata, 1336K init, 1444K bss, 167900K reserved)
[   61.998446] Memory corruption detected in low memory
```

Comment: Your bios is broken and is only reporting 4 GB of ram.  You will need to consult HP for a fix.

Comment: Where does it show the BIOS is only reporting 4GB? What I see is the BIOS reporting 8GB of RAM. Even when I enter the BIOS directly it shows 8GB.

Comment: In the e820 memory map you posted.

Comment: Dear friends the BIOS is irrelevent to this question. the title was wrong causing confusion. dmidecode clearly shows 8GB of RAM. @JessicaMeyer perhaps your problem is related to "Memory corruption detected in low memory"?

Comment: @ElderGeek the problem Ubuntu is not recognizing the 8GB ram is because of this memory corruption in low memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memorychip in slot 2 might be defective, but I do not think so.
Try swapping the two so your Nanya chip is in slot 1.
Since they are different, they might have different timing (not notiable by us humans), but the bios will think the other is off.
Swapping them will let the bios set its parameters by the Nanya chip (the lesser of the 2), and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @ken-mollerup, I can try that. But the BIOS itself does recognize the 8GB, the problem is on Ubuntu. You think that this different timing could really be the problem even though the BIOS sees both the memory cards? (Just to make sure before I venture opening up my laptop.) Cheers!

Comment: Yes but the specs are slightly different, thats why the sellers charge ekstra for 2 paired memorychips, compared to 2 normal. The computer measures memorymove in slot 1 and expect these settings to be the same for all memorychips! We humans cant messure any difference, except increased efficiency on heavy loads - with more memory - no swap!

Comment: I have swapped them as you suggested @ken-mollerup but it is still showing the same thing:

`jessy@linx:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3887       3571        315         23        224       1129
-/+ buffers/cache:       2217       1669
Swap:         8192          0       8192`

Comment: Actually the Graphics details changed to VESA: MADISON, from REDWOOD... but this could maybe be because I installed ADM Catalyst Control Center and after the reboot it automatically recognized the graphics card better somehow.

Comment: Yes the graphics is catalyst, try running the previous commands to see if its running of the Nanya chip, then it is working too! If it is not you have a problem with the Nanya chip?

Comment: the results I got were the same but just with the data from each card swapped positions (as to be expected I believe). What now? My laptop is painfully slow, I really need that 8GB RAM..

Comment: You are out of luck, your 2 memorychips don't seem to want to work together, try swapping one or the other!

Comment: Yes, I think I will end up doing that.. :( @KenMollerup Do you think that this might be something that the BIOS is retaining 4GB for Graphics (or something) and only making 4GB available? Win also detects the 8GB but says only 4GB is usable. I have tried to see that on the BIOS but the advanced options are locked..

Comment: @JessicaMeyer A 32 bit version of Windows will say 4GB available regardless. Ubuntu uses PAE on the 32-bit version so you should still see the full range available.

Comment: @ElderGeek it's Windows 7 64bit..and Ubuntu 64bit too. So that wouldn't be the problem..

Comment: I'm just underscoring that Ken is correct. 1 of your Memory modules is bad, 1 of your RAM slots is bad or the 2 aren't compatible. You should be able to determine this by swapping the modules as Ken suggests.

Comment: I tried the 4GB Samsung with my older 2GB Samsung and that worked (6GB), so I went back to where I originally bought them and they installed other 8GB and it seems to have fixed the problem. Now I have 4GB Nanya and 4GB Kingston and Ubuntu and Win7 are recognizing the whole 8GB. Thanks for your help guys, it seems it wasn't Ubuntu's problem after all.